# CSS and HTML: mark area of table with mouse tracking

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Is there an example anywhere how to select an area of a html table with tracking the mouse?
e.g. I press the mouse button and move from the second row and second column to the sixth row and fifth column - than this cells should be selected (e.g. with an other background color or a dashed border) and also the information should be fired anyhow which cells are selected -> 2/2 to 6/5.
Is there any template or example with this behaviour?
I use HTML, CSS and AngularJS in my frontend application - it would be great if an example based on this would exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the snippet below is what you are looking for. It will apply the CSS class `.hightlight` to all the cells that need to be highlighted. The global variable `range` will contain two coordinates of the selected range.

```js
assignEvents();

function assignEvents() {
  var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  
  for (let y = 0; y < rows.length; y++) {
    var cells = rows[y].children;
    
    for (let x = 0; x < cells.length; x++) {
      cells[x].onclick = function() {
        cellClick(x, y);
      }
      
      cells[x].onmouseenter = function() {
        mouseEnterCell(x, y);
      }
    }
  }
}

var selecting = false;
var anchor = {"x": 0, "y": 0};
var range = [anchor, anchor];

function cellClick(x, y) {
  var cell = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[y].children[x];
  
  if (selecting == false) {
    anchor.x = x;
    anchor.y = y;
    
    range = [anchor, anchor];
    
    selecting = true;
  } else {
    selecting = false;
  }
}

function mouseEnterCell(x, y) {
  if (selecting) {
    highlightRange(anchor.x, anchor.y, x, y);
    range = [anchor, {"x": x, "y": y}];
  }
}

function highlightRange(ax, ay, mx, my) {
  var oldRangeHighlights = document.getElementsByClassName('highlight');
  
  while (oldRangeHighlights.length > 0) {
    oldRangeHighlights[0].classList.remove('highlight');
  }
  
  if (mx < ax) {
    var tx = ax;
    
    ax = mx;
    mx = tx;
    
  }
  
  if (my < ay) {
    var ty = ay;
    
    ay = my;
    my = ty;
  }
  
  var w = (mx - ax) + 1;
  var h = (my - ay) + 1; 
  
  for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
      document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[y + ay].children[x + ax].classList.add('highlight');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

#### Explaination

The function `assignEvents()` is called on the load of the file. It gets all the rows of the table and loops them. For each `row` all the `cells` are selected and given events. `onclick` is for detecting clicks to start or stop a selection and `onmouseenter` is used for changing the live selection.

`selecting` will be true if the user is currently selecting an area
`anchor` will contain the `x` and `y` values of the original point clicked
`range` will contain anchor `x` and `y` and hovered `x` and `y` captured by the `onmouseenter` event

`cellClick()` is called when a cell is clicked. It gets the clicked cell and checks if the user is currently selecting a range. If not, it will start and defined `anchor` and `range`. If it is, it will end the selection.

`mouseEnterCell()` is called when the mouse enters a cell. If the user is selecting a range, it will update the live selection.

`highlightRange()` will highlight a range given two coordinates. First, it removes any old highlights. It will set the anchor (`ax`, `ay`) to the position highest to the top. The width (`w`) and hight (`h`) are then calculated for the box. Then they are selected and given the CSS class `highlight`.

If need you need something change just say.